# PDFmaker freezing/crashing computer?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, adobe-acrobat, pdfcreator

I convert a lot of Word documents and Powerpoints into PDFs for work. Lately my computer has consistently been freezing about once a week. I don't have enough time to sit around and wait for it to unfreeze, so I've often tried restarting. Restarting doesn't always work however as it just sits at the restart screen with the little dots going around and around (for 15+ minutes). I know it's a horrible thing to do (I feel like I'm holding it's head underwater) but I've often just done a hard restart by holding the power button. Again all this happens about once a week: freezing in the middle of work, not restarting correctly, and then needing a hard restart.

I've done some research and tried restarting it in safe mode which I am still unsure about. I need to access documents on a network and rebooting in safe mode doesn't allow me to connect to the network. So I often restart in safe mode and then just restart again in "normal mode".

This has been going on for some time and I have no idea what or how it's happening. It does consistently happen while I am trying to PDF a powerpoint or word document. Just recently I received message warning me that something was wrong with the "acrobat pdfmaker office com addin" and gave me the option to disable it. I disabled it (which means I have to PDF documents in a very roundabout way now) and I double checked to make sure I had the right programs to work with each other: Microsoft Word/Powerpoint 2013 and Adobe Acrobat XI. Does anyone know if this is a common error with PDFmaker? or if there is a different reason my computer is consistently shutting down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination (Office and Acrobat XI) should indeed work. What you could do as a first step is to Repair Acrobat (that should be in the Help menu of Acrobat).

Also, using the PDFMaker macro to create the PDFs is considered "Best Practice", because it gets most of the Word document's feature (links, cross refereces etc.) through to the PDF; something a "print to PDF" printer driver will not accomplish.

Adobe claims to have done improvements in the PDFMaker macros with Acrobat DC, which means that it might be a consideration to upgrade to Acrobat DC.

If you do not get sufficient help here, you might also ask your question in questions.acrobatusers.com, where you may encounter another group of top class experts.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose save as *.pdf
- You can download and install a pdf printer from the internet.
- There is a Microsoft Add-in if the option is not available:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7